# Can Onvif Search across network segments

Tags: c++, c, onvif

if i have a switch, ONVIF client device(a) and ONVIF Server device(b), a and b link to switch,i set ONVIF Client device(a) to zero network segments(like 192.168.0.10), ONVIF Server device(b) to be one network segments(like 192.168.1.10), a can search b?

Comment: This won't work because to use a class-C network. You can only have the last part of the IP address that differ. As you've done, you must have a `router` to route traffic between the two network segments you created. If you need more details; first read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) about network classes.

Comment: i try use NVR to  search device, it work, but i don't konw whether it use ONVIF